# Handling api requests via next.js routing

Tags: javascript, api, next.js

This is a next.js handler function for dealing with api requests on our server i need to access a variable between request methods any help will be muchly appreciated.

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
    if(req.method ===  'POST') {
        var hi = req.body
    }
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        console.log(hi)
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Just define it outside the if statements like this:

```js
export default function handler(req, res) {
    var hi = req.body
    if(req.method ===  'POST') {
        console.log(hi)
    }
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        console.log(hi)
    }
}
```